# not able to set data into database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project scaffold and stage scaffold. Project has many to one association with stage. Now I have created a task scaffold with many to one association with stage. but data from task form is not submitted to task table.

task form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with model: [@project, @stage, @task] do |form| %> 
  <% if task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :task_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :task_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Create', :class=>'button primary small' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
  def new
  @task = @stage.tasks.build
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

    @task = @project.stages.build(task_params)
    #@task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_stage
      @stage = Stage.find(params[:stage_id])
    end

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:task_name)
    end
```

Comment: Are you a friend of Anuj? :) 
What happens? Does it actually redirect to `Task#show`? What are the logs around the form submitting?

Comment: @MarekLipka You missed one important possibility: he can be Anuj himself with a new id :D

Comment: @rock and you need to replace `task` in `error_explanation` block in your form with `@task`

Comment: @ARK I didn't want to say this, but it does come to mind. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what's wrong. You have

```
@task = @project.stages.build(task_params)
```

so you're building `Stage` instead of `Task` instance here. What you actually need is:

```
@task = @stage.tasks.build(task_params)
```

I also encourage you to put some effort in actually understanding what you're doing here unless you want to ask a question on SO every half an hour of your development. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It made me smile because as a new programmer, we tend to copy and paste but forget that unless we understand, we can't go that far :-)

Inside create method, in line: `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` you are expecting params to have `project_id` but you have not passed it in the form and to pass it in form you need to have it in the first place in `new` action.

Do this:

```
  def new
    @task = @stage.tasks.build
    @project = @stage.project
  end
```

and then add this inside form:

```
  <%= form.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id %>
```

Comment: This is a nested resource (which, as I see now, OP failed to mention), so `:project_id` param should actually be present.